# Compact and Lyapunov stable n-body orbits must be smooth

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Is there a theorem that guarantees that in the case of compact and Lyapunov stable n-body orbits with Newton potential, the trajectory of each particle must be smooth? This seems very plausible but I haven't found a proof or a counter-example in the literature on the n-body problem.

**Note 1:** First, I must say that I am only interested in solutions that are compact(i.e. free from collisions and unbounded orbits) and where all masses are equal. By Lyapunov stable I mean that a slight perturbation of the initial conditions results in a compact solution that has the same shape(i.e. belongs to the same homotopy class).

**Note 2:** I suspect that if this theorem is true, then it holds for all potentials of the form $r^{-a}$ where $a>1$ and that it would also hold true for the case when the masses are not equal.

Comment: smooth as in differentiable?

Comment: @caverac Yes. I mean infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Imagine you have an orbit $\vec{r}(t)$, the velocity is smooth (differentiable) because its derivative is the force field, and that is smooth. Higher derivatives are also going to be well defined, since they are derivatives of the force field along the orbit, which is also smooth

Comment: @caverac What prevents a cusp or collision from occurring? In those cases the trajectory is no longer smooth.

Comment: Two-body encounters you can always regularize, see for instance the Kustaanheimo-Stiefel transformation for $r^{-1}$ potentials

Comment: @caverac Interesting. I'll look into this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48372/discussion-between-aidan-rocke-and-caverac).

Comment: The restricted 3-body problem has chaotic solutions for the massless body. That being the case, I think it would be difficult to show that just because none of the bodies left the system (stability) there was never a collision.